# How to add an action listener that does the same thing to different JTextField?

Tags: java, swing

Currently what I have two problems

1) How to add an action Listener that does the same thing to multiple  JTextField? I know that I have to add action Listener and simply call textField.addMouseListener(this), but what if it I have multiple JTextField? Look at the `mouseClicked` for brevity

2) When a TextField is on focus, change background color to 255, 255, 180. When a TextField loses focus, revert back to original background color. How do I accomplish this task?

Both Problem in One code:

```
public class MainFrame implements MouseListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Main Frame
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("New Account Registration");

        JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,2));
        JPanel gridGenderPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2, 4, 3));
        JPanel flowButton = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        //JLabels
        JLabel title = new JLabel("New Account Registration");

        Color newColor = new Color(255,255,180);

        // JTextFields
        JTextField nameField = new JTextField();
        nameField.addMouseListener(this);

        JTextField emailField = new JTextField();
        nameField.addMouseListener(this);

        JPasswordField passField = new JPasswordField();
        passField.addMouseListener(this);

        JPasswordField confirmPassField = new JPasswordField(); 
        confirmField.addMouseListener(this);

        JTextField addressField = new JTextField();
        addressField.addMouseListener(this);

        JTextField phoneField = new JTextField();
        phoneField.addMouseListener(this);

        gridPanel.add(title);
        gridPanel.add(nameField);
        gridPanel.add(emailField);
        gridPanel.add(passField);
        gridPanel.add(confirmPassField);
        gridPanel.add(addressField);
        gridPanel.add(countryField);


        mainFrame.add(gridPanel);   

        mainFrame.setSize(600, 700);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
            //How do i set the same thing to a different JTextField?
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: _I know that I have to add action Listener and simply call textField.addMouseListener(this)_ No, you have to call `addActionListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) you can get the other `TextField` and set the property you want on MouseClick.

For 2) You can use focus listeners.

```
focusGained(FocusEvent e)
focusLost(FocusEvent e)
```

---

```
public class MainFrame implements MouseListener, FocusListener {

    JTextField nameField;
    JTextField emailField

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }


@Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
           nameField.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
           emailField.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        }

    }

     public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

        JTextField field = (JTextField) e.getSource();
        field.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    }

    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        JTextField field = (JTextField) e.getSource();
        field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show it in detail? So i can accept your answer

Comment: This may help you get started. There is a lot of checking needs to be done like checking if e.getSource is indeed return JTextField if same FocusListner is used on other kind of components.